# Bigquery update statement by using Python APIs

Tags: google-bigquery

Before posting this I have gone through similar posts on the internet but I couldn't find the match. Apologies if it was already answered and I missed post.

I have created a python script to load the data from Google cloud storage to BigQuery via app engine. Since app engine has 60sec timeout window, want to submit these jobs in asynchronous mode and want to store the JOB ID in one of the bigquery tables. Another script will keep the status of the job and if the job is "Done" pull the results and update the jobstatus as completed in that table. so that next time I will not the check job status for the same job.

The update statement is working fine from web console if I un-select "Use Legacy SQL" but not working with API. I tried different ways like using #standardSQL in front of the query but no luck.

```
_qry = "update temp.temp set name1='xyz1' where name1='hjk'"

    job_data = {
        'jobReference': {
            'projectId': cfg._projectid,
            'job_id': str(uuid.uuid4())
        },
        'configuration': {
            'query': {
                'query': _qry,
                'timeoutMs': 60000,
                'useLegacySql': false
                },
                'allowLargeResults': True,
                'priority': 'BATCH'
            }
        }
    _jbslist = _bq.jobs()
    _jbq_response =   _jbslist.insert(projectId=_projectid,body=job_data).execute()

_jbslist = _bq.jobs()
    _job = None
    _job = 
_jbslist.get(projectId=_projectid,jobId=_jbq_response['jobReference']['jobId']).execute()
```

Comment: Do you get some `traceback` message?

Comment: This is the Error Message I got.
Errors:
query: 1.1 - 1.58: Unrecognized token update. (error code: invalidQuery)

Comment: In your JSON you have `'useLegacySql': false`. Is it how you are running your code? `false` has no definition in Python, it should be `False` but still the interpreter should have thrown an error already. Asking just to confirm.

Comment: I tried both ways "False" and "false" but getting same error. I found in one the thread need to use "false" instead of "False" so I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Update statement is working. Need to add standardSQL before the SQL.

```
    _qry1 = "#standardSQL"
    _qry  = _qry1 + "\n" + "UPDATE `tensile-site-168620.temp.temp` SET name1='chaitu1331' WHERE name1='chaitu11'"
```

table name should be with in `` these quotes `tensile-site-168620.temp.temp` then update statement is working. Thanks for your help.